# Rubocop autocorrect changed params to %i[ in rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rubocop

I'm working on a relatively new project. I upgraded from Rails 5.1.6 to Rails 5.2.

When I ran Rubocop for the first time, I got about 1800 'errors'. Most of those were `# frozen_string_literal: true` issues. I then ran `rubocop a` which inserted the string at the top of all the project files. I understand this is in preparation for Ruby 3.

One thing I noticed is that were I had certain parameters, it removed the :'s and added %i in front of the parameters. Iow, for example,

```
before_action :set_genre, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

was changed to

```
before_action :set_genre, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
```

one of my controllers where I had a hash got turned into

```
     :avatar,
                               social_id: [],
                               social_attributes: %i[site
                                                     link
                                                     active
                                                     facebook
                                                     youtube
                                                     twitter
```

I am assuming that this was a mistake generated by `Rubocop a`

Questions
 1. Is this abnormal behavior for rubocop a
 2. Am I correct in assuming that I should format the affected code back to where it was before rubocop a
 3. Is there anything I can add in the rubocop config to avoid this should I run a rubocop a again?

System

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Apatana IDE
- ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 5.2.0
- rubocop (0.55.0)

Comment: Run Rubocop with the `-D` flag, and it prints the name of the cop. Google the name, and you'll find the documentation for the cop. This is a great first place to understand what changes are made, and to see the different configurations a cop might have. In your case, the cop is [Style/SymbolArray](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/SymbolArray). Also, checking the Ruby Guide that RuboCop is based on can help understand certain rules, e.g. [collections](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/RuboCop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/SymbolArray) describes symbol arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like Robocop made a mistake. I presume the second part before rubocop looked something like `social_attributes: [:site, :link, :active, ...]`.

When writing in literal syntax (`%s[arg1 arg2] == ['arg1', 'arg2']` or `%i[arg1 arg2] == [:arg1, :arg2]`) you use less symbols, thus optimizing your code. Probably this is the reason why it is in Rubocop style-guide.

You can make rubocop ignore this by adding in you rubocop.yml

```
Style/SymbolArray:
  Enabled: false
```